# Issue with Woocommerce and extra field in orders data

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, forms

I added "VAT number" extra field in Woocommerce checkout page and in order to store meta data I have put the following code in functions.php:

```
/* Save VAT Number in the order meta */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'wda_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 2 );
function wda_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta( $customer_id, $posted ) {
    if (isset($posted['vat_number'])) {
        $dob = sanitize_text_field( $posted['vat_number'] );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'vat_number', $dob);
    }
}
```

In order to display/edit VAT Number in order edit screen I have also put the following:

```
/* Display/Edit VAT Number in order edit screen */
function wda_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
        <div class="address">
        <?php 
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'VAT n.' ) . ':</strong>' . $order->get_meta( '_vat_number' ) . '</p>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_address">
            <?php woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => '_vat_number', 'label' => __( 'VAT n.' ), 'wrapper_class' => '_billing_company_field' ) ); ?>
        </div>

<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'wda_display_order_data_in_admin' );

function wda_save_extra_details( $order_id, $post ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_meta_data( '_vat_number', wc_clean( $_POST[ '_vat_number' ] ) );
    //$order->update_meta_data( '_another_field', wc_clean( $_POST[ '_another_field' ] ) );
    $order->save_meta_data();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'wda_save_extra_details', 45, 2 );
```

The issue is that VAT number is not displayed on order page/edit.
What might be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer..I had to update also *order meta*...